# Setting HTML5 draggable attribute from codebehind not working?

Tags: c#, html

I have an table generated from the code-behind and have tried applying the HTML5 draggable attribute to its table cells.

```
TabCell.Attributes["draggable"] = "true";
```

The above applies the attribute successfully as I can see it in inspect element but the element doesn't drag.

Does anyone have any idea's why this may be?

Comment: You need to add more than that: [HTML draggable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_draggable).

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036892/html5-ondragstart-not-firing-when-attirubtes-added-through-c-sharp

Comment: draggable='true' should atleast allow you to visibly see the drag occur just not drop

Answer (score 1):

I had to set draggable through JQuery on the element.

```
$('#myid').draggable();
```

Doesn't work when the attribute is applied server-side

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what TabCell is, but assuming it's just a clientside HTML element you want to do:

```
TabCell.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
```

You don't need JQuery.  Here is some code with two tabs, both made draggable by setting the attribute as above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        .tab button {
            background-color: inherit;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        .tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <button id="TabCell1">Tab1 Header</button>
        <button id="TabCell2">Tab2 Header</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            var TabCell = document.getElementById('TabCell1');
            TabCell.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            var TabCell2 = document.getElementById('TabCell2');
            TabCell2.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```